# ASP Image button and buttons are not firing the event instead it posts the parameter on URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanna create a button/image button to pop up a panel. I have tried both image button and button and also in button both onserverclick and onclick. Anyways it is not hitting the event and it posts the parameters(randomly) in the URL like "ctl00%24MainContent%24btnNewDoc=Add+New".

```
 <asp:Button id="btnNewDoc" onserverclick="btnNewDoc_Click" Text="Add New" runat="server"/> 

 protected void btnNewDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PnlDoc.Visible = true;
        }
```

Its just a panel and it should not pass the parameter for me. And don't know the reason for this parameter passing. For this form alone, this is happening. Any idea on this.

Comment: Have you added more `form` tags or changed the page's `form` tag in some way?

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal">
                                          <ContentTemplate> <div>
                                                  <asp:Button id="btnNewDoc" onserverclick="btnNewDoc_Click" Text="Add New" runat="server"/>  
                                                </div>
                                             
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                      </form>

Comment: yes i ve added the form tag..

Comment: David, Yes i had added one more form tag. After removing that,its working fine.Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you drag a button into your view. When you click the properties. There is OnClick event. Just double click it and The code generated will be

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

So in your case it should be OnClick instead of onserverClick which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

(Just to provide an answer based on comments above to help future readers...)

In comments on the question you specify:

> i had added one more form tag

and:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
```

This is what's causing the confusion, for a couple of reasons:

1. The default form method, unless otherwise specified, is GET.  This is why the key/value pair for the button you're clicking is being added to the URL.  And the default action is the current page, so it's just reloading the page with that URL value.
2. Nesting a `form` within a `form` is effectively invalid HTML, so the actual behavior of what form submits what data is likely undefined and potentially browser-specific.  `form` elements need to be separate in HTML.
3. Adding a `form` element at all in WebForms probably isn't going to work well with the framework.  Unless things have changed since I last used WebForms, generally the framework wraps *the entire page* in a single `form` with `runat="server"`.  This form posts back to the page with all of the form information on the page every time, including a variety of `hidden` form elements used by the framework to track control state.  Creating your own form posts/actions would undermine that and cause the framework to behave in unexpected ways.

Basically you should be able to simply remove your custom `form` and allow the button to use the framework's `form` at the page level.  This should cause a standard post-back in the framework and allow the framework to use all of the associated information to map the action to the server-side click handling event.